# Angular 2 Input Directive is not clearing its view value on form reset

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I have the following directive:

```
declare  var $:any;

export const CUSTOM_INPUT_DATE_PICKER_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => SharedAppDatePickerDirective),
  multi: true
};

@Directive({
  selector: '[date-picker]',
  host: {'(blur)': 'onTouched($event)'},
  providers: [CUSTOM_INPUT_DATE_PICKER_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class SharedAppDatePickerDirective implements     ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  private innerValue: string;

  public onChange: any = (_) => { /*Empty*/ }
  public onTouched: any = () => { /*Empty*/ }

  ngOnInit() {

    $(this.el.nativeElement).datepicker().on('change', e => this.onChange(e.target.value)).on('change', e => e.target.focus());
  }

  get value(): any {
    return this.innerValue;
  };

  //set accessor including call the onchange callback
  set value(v: any) {
    if (v !== this.innerValue) {
      this.innerValue = v;
      this.onChange(v);
    }
  }

  writeValue(val: string) : void {
    this.innerValue = val;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    $(this.el.nativeElement).datepicker('destroy');
  }
}
```

When a `form.reset()` occurs, form controls where I have this directive applied to, are not clearing its view value. After `form.reset()` it becomes untouched, pristine, invalid, but it keeps the value I've typed before.

Any ideas on how to deal with?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed that by doing:

```
writeValue(val: string) : void {
    this.innerValue = val;
    this.el.nativeElement.value = val;
}
```